# $\lim_n ((\log(n+1)/(n+2))/(\log(n*(n+2)/(n+1)^2))- n$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

im kinda new in the field of mathematics, and i would really appreciate some help on the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log\frac{n+1}{n+2}}{\log\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}} - n.
$$
Thank you all for the attention!
Have a good one!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a homework solution generator. You have to show some effort yourself. I'll edit your expression. Please tell me if it is the right one. BTW, nice nickname. :D

Comment: In order to not get many downvotes, I would write out the problem in the question area and explain any efforts you made to solve it as well as where the motivation for the problem comes from.

Comment: hey, sorry for any problem caused, well this limite is not actually a homework, is kinda a investigation work on the convergence  velocity of the expression $(1+1/n)^(n+a) $ im kinda new in this writing stuff, im sorry, i've already tried to do some plots and  worked alot in this one, but im not reaching anything, sorry!

Comment: I don't like to repeat myself: Is the expression in the question area the right one?

Comment: sorry, im still trying to figure out how does this work, sorry but yes it is! thanks alot!

Comment: Do you know l'Hospital's rule? You can use it here.

Comment: well the professor who asked me to work on this one said that i should not use those aproaches because we are working in natural numbers, so it is kinda "wrong" to differentiate  ...

Comment: Even if you are not supposed to use l'Hopital in the answer, you can use it to get an idea of what the answer should be. Once you know what the limit should be you can use the $\epsilon$, $N$ approach more easily.

Comment: wow nice, i've never though about that, thanks alot!

Comment: @riemannfanboy This is a tough one without l'Hospital. The limit is $1/2$, which you can get with l'Hospital. I could reduce it to the claim $\lim_n\left(\tfrac{x_{n^2}}{x_n}\right)^n = e^{1/2}$, where $x_n := (1-\tfrac 1n)^n$. But I am unable to show this one.

Comment: Your professor is wrong about not using LHR here. If the expression has a limit  as $x\to \infty$ through real values, then it has the same limit through natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression under limit can be written as $$\frac{\log(1+a)}{\log(1+b)}-n$$ where $$a=-\frac{1}{n+2},b=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}, \frac{a^2}{b}\to - 1$$ and this can be further expressed as $$\dfrac{\log(1+a)-a+a-n\log(1+b)}{b\cdot\dfrac{\log(1+b)}{b}}$$ and clearly the denominator can be replaced by $b$. Next we split the fraction in two parts as $$\frac{\log(1+a)-a}{a^2}\cdot\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{a-n\log(1+b)}{b}$$ The first part tends to $1/2$ and the second part tends to $0$ as shown next. Split second part as $$\frac{a-nb} {b} +\frac{b-\log(1+b)}{b^2}\cdot nb$$ and both of these tend to $0$. The key here is the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ which can be established either via Taylor series or via L'Hospital's Rule or using a complicated analysis starting from the definition $$e^x=\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$ and proving the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: sorry but im not understanding why the denominator can be replaced by b

Comment: @riemannfanboy: because $b\to 0$ and consequently $\dfrac{\log(1+b)}{b}\to 1$.

Comment: i think that $\dfrac{\log(1+b)}{b}\to 1$ is not true, instead i think that $\dfrac{\log(1+b)}{b}\to log(e)$

Comment: @riemannfanboy : $\log e=1$. In calculus and real-analysis textbooks the symbol $\log$ is used to represent natural logarithm. You may use $\ln$ if you wish to avoid any ambiguity.